# how to include single sign on using 3rd party oauth server in Node-RED?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, jwt, node-red

I want to include a 3rd party authentication server in my node red application. The flow should be such that when anyone enters the link, it redirects them to the server, there they will enter credentials and on validation, they are transferred back to application. I have the client ID, authorization/token end point for that server.

Comment: Have you read the Node-RED [doc](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red#oauthopenid-based-authentication)?

Answer (score -1):

For implementing 3rd part SSO in your application there are variety of packages that can help you . One of the most popular package is passport.js . It provides support for multiple Identity providers and you can choose any package that you want

2 steps you should follow :

1. Create an application on any IDP (Identity Provider) developer's portal to get AppID , AppSecret
2. Create a setup.js file for setting up the required configuration

Have a look at this for detailed explanation https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-how-to-handle-authentication-with-node-using-passport-js-4a56ed18e81e/

While setting up the application on developer's account there are few things like RedirectURI , what is means is "this is the URL on which the access token after Authorization will be sent"

Do read about sessions and how passport helps you to easily configure this

Comment: And how does this answer the specific question about Node-RED?